# Ng-click or Ng-change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

On my website I got this:

```
<div class="tab-container">
      <div ng-if="ctrl.subCategory.level_2.length" class="tab-item active">
        <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.subCategory.level_2" class="item">
          <input type="text"
              name="{{item.name}}"
              id="{{item.name}}"
              class="link"
              resize-input="resize-input"
              ng-focus="ctrl.inputSelected = item.id; ctrl.selectSubCategory(item, 2, 3, null, true)"
              ng-change="ctrl.change(item, 3, true)"
              ng-model="item.name"
              ng-click="ctrl.selectSubCategory(item, 2, 3, null, true)"
              ng-if="item.editable === 2"
              ng-class="{ 'active': ctrl.categorySelected['level_2'].id === item.id }"
              maxlength="45"/>
          <label ng-click="ctrl.resetUnit(); ctrl.selectSubCategory(item, 2, 3, null)"
              ng-if="item.editable === 1"
              ng-class="{ 'active': ctrl.categorySelected['level_2'].id === item.id }"
              class="link link-text">
            {{ item.name }}
          </label>
          <select name="{{ item.name }}"
              custom-select="custom-select"
              options="ctrl.unitList"
              has-restart="true"
              ng-model="ctrl.unitId"
              ng-if="item.editable === 2 &amp;&amp; ctrl.inputSelected === item.id"
              destroy-if="ctrl.inputSelected !== item.id"
              class="unit-box unit-1" ></select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When user had to select unity (end of code) his clicking to set it, I just want that when his clicking on the unity he goes to the next step. For this, before we got a button here is it code:

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="!ctrl.hasValid()" ng-class="{'disable': !ctrl.hasValid()}" ng-click="ctrl.nextStep()" class="btn btn-1">Étape suivante</button>
```

In summary, I want the action `ctrl.nextStep()` of the button just when the user finish to choose is unity (in kilos, meter, M²) etc. Is it possible with `ng-click`?

If yes, where should I put my event `ng-click` in the select?

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-change

```
      <select name="{{ item.name }}"
          custom-select="custom-select"
          options="ctrl.unitList"
          has-restart="true"
          ng-model="ctrl.unitId"
          ng-if="item.editable === 2 &amp;&amp; ctrl.inputSelected === item.id"
          destroy-if="ctrl.inputSelected !== item.id"
          class="unit-box unit-1" 
          ng-change="ctrl.nextStep()"></select>
```

It is available everywhere you use ng-model.

Comment: ng-change doesn't work :/ I select all of the unity possible and I put in comment the button at the end of my page but, it stay on the same page :/.. Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

actually you can do this with ng-click too.. I'm not recommend it cause it is some hack actually but here it is;

```
<select ng-model="ctrl.unitId">
    <option value="" ng-click="ctrl.nextStep()">Some Value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank's @Erdeniz your solution works fine, but there is a problem... as you can see here : [link](http://hpics.li/16b6687) I got categories that do not need this, so if I try your solution, under "box de 33 cm" and others I'm gonna have the options list and I don't want ^^' furthermore, [link](http://hpics.li/01e0fdc) if you look my first code, you will see `class="unit-box unit-1"`where should I put it into yours ? Because if I do not insert my class, all options will be displayed on blank cube wihtout CSS :s